# EXCEL VBA macro for putting a style to a range and then ucase

Tags: excel

i'm newbie, sorry in advance for myy long question

So, i have two macros (one recorded and pasted in personal macro) and other i found in google

The first one, with my selection fills the color to orange and adds bolds borders

The second one with the selection, upercases all the range.

However, when i run this two macro together with another sub (calling the subs) the text does not shows up, i need to change of cell then select again and run the macro again in order to function.

```
Sub text ()
Dim rng As Range
Dim sAddr As String
Set rng = Selection

Selection.Merge    
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=""additional due for "" & TEXT(TODAY(),""MMMM "") & ""end of month"""   
   sAddr = rng.Address

    rng = Evaluate("index(upper(" & sAddr & "),)")

    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"

End Sub
```

Then the filling up sub (which is a little long)

```
Sub ORANGE()


Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        'CAMBIO 2
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
     Selection.NumberFormat = "General"    

End Sub
```

The way i use both macros is simply calling first ORANGE and then TEXT, beacuse the other way does not works, when i try them in VBA run macro option it works fine.

When i use the button in the ribbon i need to change of cell, select it again and it will work. i use this macro a lot but it simply makes me repeat it each time.

Does anybody knows who to perform both task at once without the result being an empty orange cell?

Thanks!

Comment: Start by reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/62576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Read comments inside the code:

```
Public Sub AddTextAndFormat()

    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Selection

    ' Merges the selection
    selectedRange.Merge
    ' Adds the formula to the first selection's cell
    selectedRange.Formula = "=""additional due for "" & TEXT(TODAY(),""MMMM "") & ""end of month"""
    ' Uppercase that first cell
    selectedRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = UCase$(selectedRange.Cells(1, 1).Value)

    ' Apply formats
    With selectedRange
        .Font.Bold = True

        ' Borders:
        .BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlMedium

        .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

        ' Other format:
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        'CAMBIO 2
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        '.MergeCells = False  -> This line unmerges the first cells merge
        .NumberFormat = "General"
    End With

    With selectedRange.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```